# How do i place an image ontop of an text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program, and i want a watermark down in the corner, and i want it to be ontop of the text widget... Insted of underneath.

The code i got:

```
from Tkinter import *

gui = Tk()

t = Text(gui)
scroll = Scrollbar(gui)
scroll.config(command=t.yview)
t.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
t.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
watermark = PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
w = Label(gui, image=watermark).pack(side="right")

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). It would look something like this:

```
w = Label(...)
w.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
```

You'll also want to make the label a child of the text widget so that the coordinates are relative to the text widget rather than relative to the window.

Comment: @MartinSolhaugStandal: of course. Labels have a borderwidth option.

Comment: One last thing, can i move it a few pixels to the left... becuse it is either over the scrollbar or underneath it...

Comment: @MartinSolhaugStandal: use both `relx` and `x` in various combinations to put it exactly where you want. However, in your case if you make the label a child of the text widget it will be in the bottom right of the text widget rather than the bottom right of the window.

Comment: @MartinSolhaugStandal: like you do with any other widget -- give the text widget as the first argument to `Label`.